# Restrict creation of VMs on GCP projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am looking to **Restrict creation of VMs on GCP projects**. Any workaround for this request.

Comment: Needs more info on the situation. Can't you just not give the role to do this to the users/service accounts that have access to the project? I guess if you don't need anything compute-engine related, you could turn of the API entirely, but this has a lot of consequences for other products as well iirc.

Comment: You can also use [org policy constraints](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [IAM Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) if you do a proper role segmentation within the users of your organization you can restrict all users/groups from creating VMw on your GCP project. Here is another link regarding [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview)

Answer (score 0):

The [compute IAM role](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam) are too broad. If you want finer control, you need to create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) without this permission `compute.instances.create`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign in IAM just permission to create instance. Here are some documentation what roles you can use.

With IAM, every API method in Compute Engine API requires that the identity making the API request has the appropriate permissions to use the resource. Permissions are granted by setting policies that grant roles to a member (user, group, or service account) of your project.

The following tables describe the predefined Compute Engine IAM roles, as well as the permissions contained within each role. Each role contains a set of permissions that is suitable for a specific task. For example, the Instance Admin roles grant permissions to manage instances, the network-related roles include permissions to manage network-related resources, and the security role includes permissions to manage security-related resources, like firewalls and SSL certificates.

```
Compute Admin role
Name    Description Permissions
roles/compute.admin 
Full control of all Compute Engine resources.
```

If the user will be managing virtual machine instances that are configured to run as a service account, you must also grant the roles/iam.serviceAccountUser role.

```
compute.*
resourcemanager.projects.get
resourcemanager.projects.list
serviceusage.quotas.get
serviceusage.services.get
serviceusage.services.list
```

[click](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam) here for more documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Set Quotas in GCP , Quota for VMs are based on the region.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#understanding_quotas
"The VM instances quota is a regional quota and limits the number of VM instances that can exist in a given region, regardless of whether the VM is running. This quota is visible in the Google Cloud console on the Quotas page. "